# node.js not retrieving any data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a beginner to node.js and trying to learn how to get data from mongodb to pass through node.js and display on the page.
I am learning it from a tutorial so follow those methods here.
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSQ1CYLHWYM&index=6&list=PL55RiY5tL51rajp7Xr_zk-fCFtzdlGKUp`

When I restart the server and load localhost it gets stuck and doesn't move forward and also does not show any errors in the terminal or the database or the console.
I am not sure why it is not showing any data in the view. My mongodb is working and listening to port `27017` and also if I go to mongod and do a `db.products.find()` I get to see all the data. Also if I just do it normally like var `products = Product.find()` it shows some data so basically there should be data coming in.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('../models/product');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.find(function(err, docs){
      console.log(docs);
     var productChunks = [];
    var chunkSize = 3;
    for( var i= 0 ; i < docs.length ; i+= chunkSize) {
        productChunks.push(docs.splice(i, i + chunkSize));
    }
      res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart' , products : productChunks});
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is the Schema for the db

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    imagePath : {type : String, required: true},
    title : {type : String, required: true},
    description : {type : String, required: true},
    price : {type : String, required: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema);
```

Here is the index.hbs

```
{{# each products}}
    <div class="row">
        {{# each this}}
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{this.imagePath}}" alt="...">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>{{this.title}}</h3>
                        <p>{{this.description}}</p>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <div class="pull-left">${{this.price}}</div>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

So I am not really sure how to tackle this problem. Since my local host is getting stuck, even if I restart the DB and server it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you log `err` and see if there are any errors

Comment: Your express server not setup yet, here you can see some basics of express with NodeJS https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that my `app.js` file was not completely configured well. I forgot to connect to `mongoose`. I solved the problem already. 
Thanks everyone who commented on this.